# How to ssh to a KVM guest VM without accessing the host?

Tags: ssh, portforwarding, kvm, ssh-tunnel

I have set up a VM and the VM is accessible from the host through the SSH also.

The host has a public IP and accessible through SSH. the guest VM can access the internet like pinging to google is working with the bridge connectivity.

For example : the host IP is ( xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)
The vm IP is ( 192.168.yyy.yyy)

Is it possible to SSH the VM without accessing the host from a different network?

Answer (score 1):

As [explained here](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-ip-address-of-linux-kvm-guest-virtual-machine/), you find out an IP address of Linux KVM guest from Linux host itself

```sh
$ virsh list
$ virsh domifaddr rhel7
```

But that does require access to the host.

You would need to configure libvirt, which  comes with its own in-build DNS server, [dnsmasq](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/doc.html), as explained in "[Automated DNS resolution for KVM/libvirt guests with a local domain](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2017/03/03/howto-automated-dns-resolution-for-kvmlibvirt-guests-with-a-local-domain/)" from [Roland Wolters](https://twitter.com/liquidat) in order to reference the guest VM directly, through a FQDN, instead of an internal IP address you cannot have without host access.

Comment: Actually, I have the IP address. I want to give access to my VM to someone but I don't want to give him access to my host.

Comment: @jaser Unless that IP is public, it would need some kind of public name (published in a DNS), and a reverse proxy to route ingress traffic to your internal private IP 192.168.yyy.yyy.